# How to find the proportion of rows the first row is less than?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` that looks like:

```
        Var1    Freq
1   Input_SNP 1.8227305
2       Set_1 1.3938528
3      Set_10 1.4295926
4     Set_100 1.3938528
5     Set_101 1.0721944
6     Set_102 1.6082916
7     Set_103 1.6082916
8     Set_104 1.6440315
9     Set_105 1.9436741
10    Set_106 1.3938528
```

I would like to find the proportion of rows that the first row is less than. For example. The first row here has a value of `1.8227305`. It is less than exactly one of the rows (row 9 is `1.9436741`). The output fraction I want is (#of rows greater than first row/#total rows -1). I subtract one because I don't want to count the first row in the #total rows. I was thinking use a `sum` some how but i don't know. Here the output should be `0.1111`

Comment: `mean(d$Freq[-1] > d$Freq[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following code:

```
> sum(data$Freq>data$Freq[1])/(length(data$Freq)-1)
[1] 0.1111111
```